# Is there any way to get element ID from previous activity launched from onclick() function in android webview?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, webview

Am trying to develop Forum Android App using Android `webview`. Currently, I am able to post topics and view them in the app. The challenge is that, I can not get the detailed information about the post on the `DetailActivity` which loads detail.php because the id from the `HomeActivity` loading home.php file where posts list are displayed does not seem to go to `DetailActivity`. I use `onClick()` function to launch `DetailActivity` from `JavaScript Interface`. Am also using Jquery and Ajax to pass the id from the clicked element to php files.

*Below is the sample code*

**Scripts and Jquery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function pageDetails() {
    Page.pageDetails();
   }
    $(function() {
    $(".readmore").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      var element = $(this);
      var msg_id = element.attr("id");
      var post_id = element.attr("data-pid");
      var phone = element.attr("data-phone");
      $("#response").show();
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://example.com/forum/details.php",
     data: "pid=" + post_id + "&phone="+ post_id,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
     $("#response").hide();

      }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

**Part of HomeActivity.java**

```
 public class PageDetails {
        Context mContext;
        PageDetails(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void pageDetails(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

**Html part of home.php**

```
<a class="readmore" href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?php echo $pid;?>" data-pid="<?php echo $pid;?>" data-phone="<?php echo $phone;?>" style="text-decoration: none; width: 100%;" onclick="pageDetails(this.id)"> Read more </a>
```

**detail.php**

$post_id = $_POST['pid'];

From the above sample code, when I click **Read more**, DetailActivity opens in webview where detail.php is loaded without value from HomeActivity

Please help

Comment: there seems to be no interaction or relation between `detail.php` and `HomeActivity.java` Also, I'm fairly sure you cant call a Java class method from Javascript as you are trying to do here?

Comment: pass id from HomeActivity to DetailActivity via intent extra.
Now get id in DetailActivity and load url with that id as query parameter and get that id in your javascript code of web and use it

Comment: This works perfectly for me